# Angular2, factory guard is possible?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular-guards

I have a lot of trusts in my website, so to make secure routes I build the next guard:

```
export class TrustGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return /*Check if user has the trust or not*/;
    }
}
```

So, in the routes I will can add the guard like `canActivate: [TrustGuard]`

The problem is that I have too many trusts, consequently I would need to build one guard for each trust. So I'm trying to build a factory of guards that to avoid to implements too many similar guards.

My target is to find the way of set the route like 
`canActivate: [FactoryTrustGuard(Trust.seeDashboard)]`

Is it that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameters to constructor of canActivate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624086/how-to-pass-parameters-to-constructor-of-canactivate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will likely create problems with AOT, because route definitions are supposed to be static.

The guards can DRYed up to eliminate most boilerplate code:

```
export abstract class TrustGuard  {
    protected abstract trust: string;

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        /* check against this.trust */
    }
}

export class FooTrustGuard extends TrustGuard {
    protected trust = Trust.foo;
}
```

If there are tens of similar guards, it is possible to make it a single guard and pass a role through route data:

```
export class TrustGuard  {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        const trust = route.data['trust'];
        if (trust in Trust) {
          ...
        } else {
          throw ...;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
{ route: ..., canActivate: [TrustGuard], data: { trust: Trust.seeDashboard } }
```