# How to pass parameters to constructor of canActivate?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have the following route path:

```
{
    path: 'teacher',
    component: DashboardTeacher, canActivate: [AccessGuardTeacher('Teacher')]
}
```

As you can see I tried to pass parameter 'Teacher' in class `AccessGuardTeacher`:

```
export class AccessGuardTeacher implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private role: string) {
  }
}
```

How to do that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Angular 14+ Solution**

```
{
    path: 'edit',
    component: Cmp,
    canActivate: [
      () =>
        inject(Service).hasUserPermissions(['WRITE_SOMETHING'])
          ? true
          : inject(Router).parseUrl('/goSomewhere'),
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 25):

Your route should be configured like:

```
{ 
   path: 'teacher', 
   component: DashboardTeacherComponent, 
   canActivate: [AccessGuardTeacher], 
   data: { 
            role: 'teacher'
         } 
}
```

Get your route data in your CanActivate Guard

```
export class AccessGuardTeacher implements CanActivate {

     constructor() {
     }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

        const role = route.data.role;
        return true; //based on your condition
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try this way:

{
    path: 'teacher',
    component: DashboardTeacher, canActivate: [AccessGuardTeacher],
    data: {type: ['Teacher']}
}

export class AccessGuardTeacher implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private role: string) {
  }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    let type = route.data["type"] as Array<string>;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anuglar 16+ Solution (CanActivateFn)

```
    {
    path: 'myModule',
    loadChildren: (): any => import('./view/myModule/myModule.module').then(m => m.MyModule),
    canActivate: [RolesAllowedGuard],
    data: {
        rolesAllowed: [
            OrgRoleEnum._7Lmva,
            OrgRoleEnum._6Lmvs,
            OrgRoleEnum._5Sa,
            OrgRoleEnum._4A,
            OrgRoleEnum.SuperuserIdp,
            OrgRoleEnum._3Su,
            OrgRoleEnum._2Lp]
    }
}
```

---

```
export const RolesAllowedGuard: CanActivateFn = (guardRolesAllowed) => {
const userState: UserState = inject(UserState);
const router: Router = inject(Router);

return userState.orgRole$.pipe(
    filter(role => role !== OrgRoleEnum.NotSet),
    map((role) => {
        const rolesAllowed = guardRolesAllowed.data["rolesAllowed"];
        if (rolesAllowed && rolesAllowed.includes(role)) {
            return true;
        }
        return router.createUrlTree(['/startpage'])
    })
  );
```

};