# How to pass Subscription content into CanDeactivateGuard

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a CanDeactivateGuard for my routes and I want to pass data to it. The guard just prompts a user to save any unsaved changes. It launches a modal dialogue and the data I want to pass into the dialogue comes from a Subscription.

I was using this answer as a guide for my problem: [How to pass parameters to constructor of canActivate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624086/how-to-pass-parameters-to-constructor-of-canactivate)

...but it seems a bit oversimplified for what I'm doing because I can't pass a Subscription along with my routes, as far as I know.

Here's my guard:

```
export class PendingChangesGuard
  implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  constructor(
    private myDialogService: MyDialogService,
  ) {}

  canDeactivate(
    component: ComponentCanDeactivate,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate() || this.openConfirmDialog();
  }

  openConfirmDialog() {
    const ref = this.myDialogService.open(MyDialogComponent, /** Pass a CONFIG object here **/);
    return ref.afterClosed$();
  }
}
```

You can see in the `modalDialogService.open()` method I want to pass that data as the 2nd argument.

Here's how I've implemented fetching the content in another component that uses different data from the same service call:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  myContent: any;
  myContentSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private myContentService: MyContentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myContentSubscription = 
this.myContentService.myContent$.subscribe(
      flag => {
        if (flag) {
      this.myContent = this.myContentService.getMyContent();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

This `myContentSubscription` will populate the data that I need to pass when I open the modal. My assumption is that my Guard should not be implementing the call to this service, it's not the Guard's responsibility. Plus, because the call is asynchronous I'll have to wait to be able to pass the data into the modal.

Where is the right place to put that subscription code so the Guard has access to it when it's invoked?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone else who comes across this issue --

The *app.component.ts* calls the *HomePageTridionContentService* when the application loads. This means that by the time my *Guard* comes into play the service has already retrieved the data and I can simply do this in the *Guard* to get at it:

```
openConfirmDialog() {
    const modalData = 
this.homePageContentService.getModalContent();
    const config = { data: { ...modalData } };
    const ref = this.modalDialogService.open(ModalDialogComponent, 
config);
    return ref.afterClosed$();
}
```