# Angular - capture router path pattern in canActivate

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following situation:

**Router**

```
{
        path: 'tab1',
        canActivate: [GuardService],
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1/:id',
        canActivate: [GuardService],
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1/:id/reports',
        canActivate: [GuardService],
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      }
```

I want to control the access in each URL / path.

In my AuthService I've the following validation:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {  
    if (this.auth.hasPermission(state.url) === 1) return true;
  }
```

It works with static values as "tab1" because I can compare "tab1" with my DB value "tab1".
But if I need permission over parametric paths, I'm in trouble.

**state.url** return me, for example, "tab1/1" or "tab1/23"...; is dynamic, but in my DB I need compare with "tab1/:id" because **id** is a dynamic value.

I can't find an attribute, method or some like that, in ActivatedRouteSnapshot or RouterStateSnapshot, than return me the current pattern in the path, just **"tab1/:id"**

Can you help me?

Comment: Hey I think there is a solution for you in this link [How to pass parameters to constructor of canActivate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624086/how-to-pass-parameters-to-constructor-of-canactivate). Best wishes :-)

Comment: Tks @Linker, your approach was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @Linker recommendation, I did:

```
{
    path: 'tab3',
    data: { 
      url: '/tabs/tab3'
    },
    canActivate: [GuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tab3/:id',
    data: { 
      url: '/tabs/tab3/:id'
    },
    canActivate: [GuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
  }
```

And My AuthService was changed by:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.auth.hasPermission(route.data.url) === 1) return true;
}
```

It works fine!

The @Akash aproach is great and works when I have just one level of path (tab1/:id). Each additional level of depth in the URL (tab1/:id/:param)..., implies that I need an additional regex in the canActivate method; However is other good solution.

Answer (score 1):

To check for dynamic value, use regex to check weather your URL is valid or not.

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {  
    if ((tab1\/\d+).test(this.auth.hasPermission(state.url))) return true;
  }
```

it will return true if url fits in tab1/.

Thanks